# retrieving rows with max date

Tags: sql

I have two tables like this:

```
Table1 (Number column is unique)

Number | date

1234      2008-10-06 17:11:00

5678      2005-10-19 16:20:00

9023      2005-12-09 16:20:00

4243      2009-01-06 17:11:00

5234      2009-01-14 17:11:00



Table 2 

Number | code  

1234     A1   

1234     B1 

5678     A1

9023     A1

4243     C1

5234     C1
```

I am trying to retrieve data from these two tables so that I get only one row for each code in Table 2 that is the most recent (from table 1).

Based on this example, my result would be:

1234  A1 (because thats the one with latest date)

1234  B1 (because thats the one with latest date)

5234  C1 (because thats the one with latest date)

Answer (score 3):

```
Select Distinct T1.number, T2.code 
From Table2 T2 
   Join Table1 T1
       On T1.Number = T2.Number
           And T1.date =
              (Select Max(Date) From Table1
               Where Number = T2.Number)
```

EDIT: to fix issue noted in comment:

```
 Select Z.Number, Z.Code
  From (Select A.number, A.code, B.date
        From Table2 A Join Table1 B
           On B.Number = A.Number) Z
  Where Z.Date =
      (Select Max(Date) 
       From Table2 A Join Table1 B
           On B.Number = A.Number
       Where code = Z.Code)
```

Comment: This is the classic method.  I prefer using analytics nowadays (see other answer).  You should test the performance, and how they handle duplicates if that matters, to decide which one is better for you.

Comment: Dave, unknown did not specify a database. I don't use Oracle, I have never run into analytics. I will check into it for PostgreSQL though.

Comment: Dave,  I'm not familiar with "Analytics" - ahh well another area to get familiar with!  -  and only so many empty glial cells left you know...

Comment: This does not work. This returns the following results
1234       A1        
1234       B1        
4243       C1        
5234       C1        
5678       A1        
9023       A1
This returns 5678 and 9023. which should not show up. because 1234's date is the latest....

Comment: it works fine if select is changed to select distinct(t2.code) but problem is go get the number as well.  If number is added then everything is fetched!

Answer (score 1):

Analytic function solution.  This is for Oracle; if you're using another RDBMS it may not work.  If there are multiple rows with the same date for a given code, this will arbitrarily select one.

```
SELECT number, code FROM (
  SELECT t1.number,
         t1.code,
         row_number() OVER ( PARTITION BY t1.code ORDER BY t2.date DESC ) date_sort_key
    FROM t1, t2
    WHERE t2.number = t1.number
  )
  WHERE date_sort_key = 1
```

Substituting rank() for row_number() would make it report multiple entries where there is a duplicate date.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version of Dave's answer that works on SQL Server

```
 SELECT number, code FROM (
  SELECT Table2.number,
         Table2.code,
         row_number() OVER ( PARTITION BY table2.code ORDER BY table1.date DESC ) date_sort_key
    FROM table1, Table2
    WHERE Table2.number = table1.number
  ) a
  WHERE date_sort_key = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for SQL SERVER

```
CREATE table Table1 (number int, date datetime)
INSERT Table1 VALUES (1234, '2008-10-06 17:11:00')
,(5678, '2005-10-19 16:20:00')
,(9023, '2005-12-09 16:20:00')
,(4243, '2009-01-06 17:11:00')
,(5234, '2009-01-14 17:11:00')

CREATE table Table2 (number int, code varchar(2))
INSERT Table2 VALUES (1234, 'A1   ')
,(1234, 'B1') 
,(5678, 'A1')
,(9023, 'A1')
,(4243, 'C1')
,(5234, 'C1')

SELECT DISTINCT
  a.number
 ,a.code
FROM Table2 a
  INNER JOIN Table1 b ON a.number = b.number
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      t2.code
     ,MAX(t1.date) as date
    FROM Table2 t2
      INNER JOIN Table1 t1
        ON t1.Number = t2.Number
    GROUP BY t2.code
  ) c ON b.date = c.date
```