# SQL Latest date

Tags: sql

I thought I had it but it seemed I was wrong.

I have a query

```
select PrestatieCode, Uitvoerdatum, Identificatie, Foutmelding 
from bam_Zending_AllInstances as zAll
left outer join bam_Zending_CompletedRelationships as zRel on 
zAll.ActivityID = zRel.ActivityID
left outer join bam_Prestatie_AllInstances as pAll on 
zRel.ReferenceData = pAll.ActivityID
where zAll.Zender = 'BL15' 
and ReferenceType = 'Activity' 
and Zendingnummer = '632'
```

This shows a list of PrestatieCodes, also duplicates.
Now I only need to have a list of PretatieCodes without the duplicates, it should just pick the one with the lastest date. The datecolumn = Uitvoerdatum.

I thought I'd try something like:

```
select max(Uitvoerdatum), PrestatieCode  
from bam_Zending_AllInstances as zAll
left outer join bam_Zending_CompletedRelationships as zRel on 
zAll.ActivityID = zRel.ActivityID
left outer join bam_Prestatie_AllInstances as pAll on 
zRel.ReferenceData = pAll.ActivityID
where zAll.Zender = 'BL15' 
and ReferenceType = 'Activity' 
and Zendingnummer = '632'
group by PrestatieCode
```

which gives me what I want. However as you can notice it does not have the 2 columns "Identificatie" and Foutmelding. If I add these it gives me the error

```
Column 'bam_Prestatie_AllInstances.Identificatie' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

So I'm guessing my approach is wrong. I need to see all the columns but only for the latest "PrestatieCode"s.

Am I making any sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any schema it is a tad difficult. But what you need to try is getting the id and max value (so in your case PrestatieCode and MAX(Uitvoerdatum) and then do a sub join)

```
SELECT  YourTabel.*
FROM    YourTabel INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  PrestatieCode,
                    MAX(Uitvoerdatum) MaxDates
            FROM    YourTabel
            WHERE   YourCondition
            GROUP BY PrestatieCode 
        ) YourTableMaxDates ON  YourTabel.PrestatieCode = YourTableMaxDates.PrestatieCode
                            AND YourTabel.Uitvoerdatum = YourTableMaxDates.MaxDates
```

This should get you the latest data per PrestatieCode

Comment: +1: Could use table aliases - less likely to scroll off screen.

Comment: Thanks for replies! I decided i'd split up the query in different ones, because there were even more parameters which had to be joined. So i used a combination of c# and querries to do the job, which after some testing also gave the best performances.

Answer (score 1):

In your second query, you're saying that you want *one* row for each unique `PrestatieCode`. So a result set of possibly several rows with the same `PrestatieCode` will be merged into one row. The value of `PrestatieCode` is given, because it is the same across all of these rows (if we're considering one particular group). The value of `Uitvoerdatum` is also easy: you're telling the server to just pick the max one. What about `Identificate`, then? It could be of several different values, and you haven't specified which one to pick. If it doesn't matter, you could do `max(Identificate)` as well. If you know that they're always gonna be the same, for all `PrestatieCode`s that are the same, you can safely throw that value into the `group by` clause as well.

Whatever you decide on, you need to give the sql server some clues regarding which values you're interested in.

Comment: that's right.
If the other columns are always the same value and just the date change, you can either group them by those value or use MAX.If they really don't matter and you don't need them, just remove them from your select.

Comment: haha, well yeah, that's a better approach than mine, hey? i tried to cover the *either in an aggregate function* part of the error message, but yes, that was a nonsensical example.

Answer (score 0):

You can also put the second one (simplified as much as possible since you only want the two columns) in a subquery in the "from" clause, give it a name, and use it in a join to limit the output of the first query to the line having the values from the second query.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question has been answered before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448478/retrieving-rows-with-max-date).  You'll notice that the best solution depends on what server you are using, since many have special functionality to improve these queries.